# Why does this @mention regex not work?

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have this regex

```
/(?:[\s.]|^)@(\w+\.?(?:\w+))/g
```

This incorrectly gives me the period before the mention- for example

```
.@blah.
```

has the prior full stop matched and captured.

Further, when I do this -

End of sentence.@foo.Start of sentence

It captures `.@foo.Start`

when I want it to only capture @foo

When I have this regex -

```
/(?:\s|^)@(\w+\.?(?:\w+))/g
```

All the cases work except

```
.@foo. and End of sentence.@foo.Start of sentence
```

In those cases, nothing is matched.

How should I change this regex?

Code(although I'm not really sure why this would help)

```
text.replace(/(?:\s|^)@(\w+\.?(?:\w+))/g, function(match, p1) {
            var text = match,
                link = '/' + $.trim(text).slice(1);
            return '<a href="' + link + '" target="_blank">' + text + "</a>";
        });
```

EDIT- clarity

Ok so I guess the above was not clear.

If I have this sentence `bladi bladh.@praks5432.Bladi blah`
I want to capture `@praks5432`

If I have this sentence `bladi bladh.@praks5432`
I want to capture `@praks5432`

If I have `@praks5432..`
I want to capture `@praks5432`

If I have `.@praks5432.`
I want to capture `@praks5432`

Comment: Please give us the code you use, it's hard to follow what you do here.

Comment: It would also help if you'd show a bit more of what exactly you want to accomplish.

Comment: added...but it really shouldn't matter - this is a regex question

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to get the captured group in a matching string, don't use the g flag :

```
".@blah.".match(/(?:[\s.]|^)@(\w+)/)
```

gives

```
[".@blah", "blah"]
```

so you just have to use the element at index 1.

Comment: edited the question - should be a little more clear, let me know if it isn't

Comment: If not, can you give an example of the complete string ? Here I think using $1,$2,etc. would be simpler than to use a function ([very relevant example](https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/src/client-scripts/miaou.format.js#L25)).

Answer (score 1):

So basically, you just want a word preceded by a `.@`?

that would be `/\.@(\w+)/`. If you want to capture the `@`, just use `/\.(@\w+)/`

likes so

`"if i .@praks5432.".match(/\.(@\w+)/)[1]`       **Note:** [1] = capture group one

**UPDATE:**

Do you want a word preceded by a (`.` or the start of a line) and a `@`?

an OR would require a non-capture group. The phrase `(?:^|\.)` means start of a line (`^`) or dot (`\.`). The `?:` means the group shouldn't be captured.

So that would be `"@praks5432.".match(/(?:^|\.)(@\w+)/)[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but to just capture from before the `@` to before the next `.` it would be

```
 #  /(?:[\s.]|^)(@\w+)\.?\w+/

 (?: [\s.] | ^ )
 (@ \w+ )            # (1)
 \.? 
 \w+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, it will capture everything from @ to ., excluding the .

```
@.*(?=\.)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simplify your regular expression. Use this `@(\w+)`.

I tested it at regexpal.com

Comment: Why not just `@(\w+)`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you want to match user names in some text block, but not emails. If so, maybe this is appropriate:

```
/(?:\W|^)(@\w+)/g
```

Now your mistake in the replace call is that it will replace the entire matched region, including the char before the user name (if any). Negative look-behind is usually used for that, but it's not available in JS, instead you can do:

```
text.replace(/(\W|^)(@\w+)/g, function(match, p1, p2) {
        var text = p2,
            link = '/' + text.slice(1);
        return p1 + '<a href="' + link + '" target="_blank">' + text + "</a>";
    })
```